# Does spring support FullyQualified bean name?

Tags: spring

Looks like `FullyQualified` is a good feature, does Spring support it, if not any plan to support it?

http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/latest/reference/en-US/html/solder-programmingmodel.html#d0e458

> 4.5. @FullyQualified bean names
>
> According to the CDI standard, the @Named annotation assigns a name to
>   a bean equal to the value specified in the @Named annotation or, if a
>   value is not provided, the simple name of the bean class. This
>   behavior aligns with the needs of most application developers.
>   However, framework writers should avoid trampling on the "root" bean
>   namespace. Instead, frameworks should specify qualified names for
>   built-in components. The motivation is the same as qualifying Java
>   types. The @FullyQualified provides this facility without sacrificing
>   type-safety.

Comment: Since `@FullyQualified` is JBoss Seam-specific and not part of CDI, I would guess not.

Comment: any similar thing?if not support the same